# Understanding the philosophy behind the axiomatic definition of reals

Tags: real-analysis, logic, definition, real-numbers

I have just recently started to read a book about mathematics and have stumbled upon an axiomatic definition of the real numbers. The real numbers are defined as a Dedekind-complete ordered field. While I understand the components of this definition, i.e the specifications of these axioms, I am absolutely lost as to the philosophical process in place. 
We define the real numbers by a set of properties that we assume to be true.
If someone was to try and construct the set of real numbers using this definition, he would have to turn to the only set that has these properties. Which set is that? It is the set that we assume to have these properties. Well, which set is that? It is the set that we assume to have these properties and so on... I feel like without a concrete reference of some sort all we're left with is cyclical logic.
Can anybody help me shed light on the philosophical process of this definition?

Comment: Try a philosopher perhaps?

Comment: All I'm interested in is making very basic sense of the process in this definition. Surely that would not require a philosopher.

Comment: Well your concern is genuine. You should better get familiar with the construction of real numbers as given by Dedekind to get the real feeling of the way they work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inference "If ... . he would have to turn to the only set that has these properties" is not a mathematical inference and rests on non-mathematical presuppositions. In particular, you simply presuppose that the axiom-system characterizes the real numbers strictly uniquely (up to equality in some universe of sets); this is *not* the usual point of view nowadays. At most 'uniqueness up to isomorphism of ordered fields' is usually considered, and for *that* you even *forgot* to mention a condition: the real numbers [are](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624087/who-first-proved-that-the-second-order-theory-of-real-numbers-is-categorical?rq=1) the only complete ordered field, up to isomorphism of ordered fields.

A similar comment is in order in response to your question "Which set is that?" This question presupposes a view which is considered outdated: that any property (like e.g. 'satisfying all the axioms you are currently asking about') would define  a set. G. Frege, among others, thought that something similar could be adopted as a principle of thought, but this turned out to be an untenably naive point of view. As user87690 has already hinted at,  in usual set-theory *there are infinitely-many sets which are isomorphic as fields to the real numbers*.

The intuition you evince in " I feel like without a concrete reference of some sort all we're left with is cyclical logic"<sup>(usage)</sup> is quite relevant: the [Axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) arguably arose out of a similar intuition.

Re your "Can anybody help me shed light on the philosophical process of this definition?": the 'philosophical process' is that usually only the isomorphism type is considered essential *for mathematical and scientific applications of $\mathbb{R}$*, while the set-theoretic realization is considered a, as it were, [set-and-forget](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set-and-forget)<sup>(pun)</sup> issue of (model-)theoretic interest only. Relevant keywords with which you can learn more are 'axiomatic method' and 'model theory' (where a relevant topic to learn about is [categoricity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624087/who-first-proved-that-the-second-order-theory-of-real-numbers-is-categorical?rq=1)).

${}$_______________________________

<sup>(pun)</sup> Pun intended. The model is usually taken to be a *set* which for most intents and purposes you then forget.

<sup>(usage)</sup> By the way, 'circular logic', or 'circular reasoning' is a *much* more usual collocation in English.

Comment: Thank you, you have referenced many things in your response which I have yet to familiarize myself with. I have a lot of reading to do. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually up too isomorphism there is only one complete ordered field. It's not hard to show that a complete ordered field must be Archimedean.

Comment: And saying "only the isomorphim type is considered essential, not the set-theoretic realization" seemms to gloss over what seems to me to be the point to the question: How do we know that there _is_ a compete ordered field?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich There is a small issue in some books/contexts using "complete" for "Cauchy complete" (which doesn't imply Archimedean) and others using it for "Dedekind complete" (which does). But I agree with you wholeheartedly that the primary issue is likely "why should something satisfying those axioms exist?"

Comment: Simple proof that any Dedekind-complete ordered field is Archimedean: Suppose not: $\epsilon>0$ but $\epsilon/le1/n$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $n\le1/\epsilon$ for every $n$, so $\Bbb N$ is bounded above. Hence $\Bbb N$ has a least upper bound. But it's clear that $\Bbb N$ does _not_ have a least upper bound, because if $b$ is an upper bound then $b-1$ is a smaller upper bound.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: thanks for pointing out. I misremembered. Will edit.

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks. My first reaction was that the two notions of completeness are equivalent. Second reaction: Oops, that equivalence uses the Archimedean property. (Of course the OP _did_ specify "Dedekind-complete"...)

Comment: When you say "there are infinitely many sets which are isomorphic as fields to the real numbers", how are you counting the sets? What additional structure are you assuming which allows you to distinguish two sets as being "isomorphic as fields" but "unequal"?

Comment: @tparker: one can use that the singleton-classfunction $x\mapsto\{x\}$ does not have any fixed point. If $\mathbb{Q}$ denotes any specified  realization of the rational numbers in ZF set theory, and if $\{(L,U)\colon L\in\mathfrak{L}\subseteq2^{\mathbb{Q}},\ U\in\mathfrak{U}\subseteq2^{\mathbb{Q}}\}$ is any set of Dedekind cuts which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ when endowed with the usual addition and multiplication of Dedekind cuts, then for any $k\in\omega$ the set $\{   \{^k(L,U)\}^k \colon L\in\mathfrak{L}\subseteq2^{\mathbb{Q}},\ U\in\mathfrak{U}\subseteq2^{\mathbb{Q}}\}$ [...]

Comment: [...] where $\{^k$ and $\}^k$ denotes the relevant strings of braces is a different set from all other such realizations, but is isomorphic to all the others when endowed with the suitably altered addition and multiplication of Dedekind cuts. This gives countably-infinitely many distinct realizations of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @tparker: and re "What additional structure are you assuming which allows you to distinguish two sets as being "isomorphic as fields" but "unequal"?": no "additional structure" is necessary; rather, what is used is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality which axiomatically defines what it means for two sets in ZF-set theory to be unequal.

Answer (score 16):

It seems like a better question to me than some people seem to think. The question of which set we're talking about doesn't matter, but the question of how we know such a structure *exists* certainly matters. Lemme paraphrase what it seems to me the issue is, in language that people  here will understand:

**Q:** I've read that the reals are a complete ordered field. Ok, one can easily show that any two (Dedekind-)complete ordered fields are isomorphic, so this characterizes the theory of the reals, fine. But how do we know that a complete ordered field *exists*? After all, if there's no such thing as a complete ordered field then the theory of complete ordered fields seems a little pointless.

A perfectly reasonable *mathematical* question; no need to snicker about the need for a philosopher. Luckily:

**A:** There are various methods one can use to show that a complete ordered field exists. One of the best known is via "Dedekind cuts", which you can read about in various places online.

Answer (score 12):

Axiomatic definition like this doesn't tell you “this particular thing is the set of reals”, but rather “we call the reals anything that satisfies the conditions”. It just specifies the interface, not giving any particular implementation.

The point here is that not only some implementation exists, but that it is unique up to isomorphism. This is not part of the definition, it is a theorem that has to be proved. But it justifies the name “the reals” (i.e. using the definite article).

Actually, it doesn't matter which particular set realizes the reals, the structure is important. You can for example look at a simpler case of natural numbers and integers – do you know their actual set theoretic representation? (There are some natural choices, maybe one of them is considered canonical.) Does it really matter? I mean, the structure itself is important, and the fact that it can be realized as a set. But the particular realization is not so important.

Axiomatic definitions are more often used in the situation without uniqueness – vector spaces, metric spaces, topological spaces, Banach spaces – they are axiomatically defined structures/interfaces that abstract over particular instances, so you can formulate some theorems that hold in general.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I understand now that the structure of this set is more important than any particular realization. And I understand there is esentially only one set that holds these properties. But how do we know which set holds these properties? How can I know that the set that contains every number represented by an infinite string of decimals actually holds these particular properties?

Comment: “How can I know?” – as always in math, you have to prove that. A simpler thing: can you actually prove that the set of all integers with addition satisfies the axioms of commutative groups? On one hand, rather obvious, on the other hand, you have to consider some actual construction of integers.

Comment: @PeterHeinig: If you want to represent all reals as decimal strings, you have to also encode the sign, and then $0$ has also two representatives.

Comment: @PeterHeinig what are the two decimal representations of $1/3$? I only know one (0.3333333...)